# client.print String/Char from sparkfun scanner

Tags: php, c++, arduino, client

Im trying to sent a the content from a QR code via Sparkfun DE2120 scanner and UNO.
The problem is when I try to send the data to the myadmin DB.

In the serial monitor the QR is a string but in the phpmyadmin it is not appear:
Code bellow:

```
  #include "SparkFun_DE2120_Arduino_Library.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include <Ethernet.h>
#define BUFFER_LEN 40


    byte mac[] = {
    0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xEE }; // 
    IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 22 );  //
    IPAddress gateway(10, 74, 0, 1); 
    IPAddress subnetMask(255, 255, 255, 192); 
    EthernetClient cliente;
    char server[] = "192.168.1.15"; // 

SoftwareSerial softSerial(3,2);
DE2120 scanner;

char scanBuffer[BUFFER_LEN];
String QR; 




void setup() {

  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  softSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(scanner.begin(softSerial));

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
      IPAddress newSubnet(255, 255, 255, 192);
      Ethernet.setSubnetMask(newSubnet);
      Serial.print("Ethernet.localIP: ");
      Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
      Serial.print("Ethernet.gatewayIP:");
      Serial.println(Ethernet.gatewayIP());
      Serial.print("Ethernet.subnetMask:");
      Serial.println(Ethernet.subnetMask());
      
      if (cliente.connect(server, 8080)) {
        Serial.println("Connected to the server");}
}

void loop() {
  
 delay(200);

  if(scanner.readBarcode(scanBuffer, BUFFER_LEN)){
    QR = scanBuffer; // String
    delay(2000);
    Serial.print("QR availbale: ");
    (cliente.connect(server, 8080));
    cliente.print("GET /ethernet/data_qr.php?");
    cliente.print("QR=");
    cliente.println(QR);
    cliente.stop();
    
    Serial.println(QR);
    delay(1000);     
        
}

}
```

The value from the serial.monitor:

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: The problem is more likely in the PHP/server side. Have you checked the server logs to see what happens there? Or otherwise tried to debug your server-side? What happens if you paste the URL with the example QR code? What does the server reply with?

Comment: your HTTP request is not complete. and print the response too. see the WebClient example

Comment: Hello , I tried to print another char or string and it works, that makes me think that HTTP request is ok.